# REST Get Call in Java for Pagination

Tags: java, rest

I'm using a REST Client to do a GET All Users using Java. I have this working, I have a method different for Retrieving All Users and Retrieving User by ID. In the All Users Method I want to add a pagination logic, where instead of this url /api/v1/Users I should be able to give /api/v1/Users?count=10 . Is there any way I can read the value 10 from the url for the All Users method? Currentl My method looks like this.

```
@GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response retrieveAll() {
......

...

return response
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Response retrieveAll(@QueryParam("count") Integer count) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot, is there any documentation for this, for example if I want to know how to add multiple queries like  /api/v1/Users?setIndex=2&count=10

Comment: Also, is there any way I can make this as optional? For example now will it make me mandatory to give a Query, or I can still run /Users without any query and get a result?

Comment: No, if you do not specify the parameter, its value will be NULL.  There is no way to make a parameter mandatory in JAX-RS.